# Magento 2 show name instead of id in Layered Navigation

Tags: magento2, category, url, layered-navigation, link

I'm using Magento 2, and on the category pages, on the left, where are listed all the subcategories, if I click on any of them, I get a link ending in: `?cat=id`

If I try to follow the same path from the main menu, I get: `/subcategoryname.html`

Would it be possible to have it like that also on the layered navigation? I've been loking into magento files, and found this: `/vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/templates/layer/filter.phtml`

with this part of code: `<a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($filterItem->getUrl()) ?>">`

working out that link, it would be fine editing this, and how? or it would work better another way?

Answer (score 1):

If you tried using category url instead of **?cat=catId** then layered navigation not working properly. If you don't care layered nav, then try following way:

**VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item">
        <plugin name="VendorName_ModuleName::layered_filter_item" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Item.php**

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter;


class Item
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $categoryFactory;

    /**
     * Item constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterfaceFactory $categoryFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterfaceFactory $categoryFactory
    ) {
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Get filter item url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function aroundGetUrl(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        if($subject->getFilter()->getRequestVar() == 'cat') {
            $catId = $subject->getValue();
            $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($catId);
            return $category->getUrl();
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```